# Drop Constraint - Relation does not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I'm trying to drop a table constraint using Postbird interface or the following SQL:

```
alter table devices 
drop constraint FK_473c90a9cf5f18226886e62a3b3
```

Both way, error is:
constraint "fk_473c90a9cf5f18226886e62a3b3" of relation "devices" does not exist

**Table structure**
[image]

**information_schema.table_constraints**
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Use double Quotes for the constraint name. Otherwise it gets lowercased.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me (Double Quotes).

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer as per @clamp's reply:

```sql
alter table devices 
drop constraint "FK_473c90a9cf5f18226886e62a3b3"
```